# Namespace issue with MVC view - Razor engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I added reference to the System.Web.DataVisualization to my MVC project.
Now when I try to add the namespace to my web.config I am getting error

CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

So then I try to use the same in my controller. This works perfectly.

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization;
```

Then the same should work in my Razor view

So I try to use this in my Razor view

```
@using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization;
```

This again not not work giving me the same error

How come I can use the namespace in my controller and not in my views?

Am I missing something...

Comment: sarath i am try with you and got the same problem. well how you find the dll for your project. i myself at a step never found that this is part of .net

Comment: System.Web.DataVisualization component comes with .Net 4.0

Comment: I got exactly the same problem... no solution so far

Comment: It seems strange though that I can add the namespace for controllers but not for views

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to the project references, go to properties on "System.Web.DataVisualization," then set "CopyLocal" to true, you'll then be able to put

```
@using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization
```

in your Razor view.

Answer (score 0):

This made me curious so I just tried it myself.
It works fine.
Make sure you add your namespace to the Web.Config in the 'Views' folder (not the root web.config).

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suspect it throws error only if you try to use the same in your view. After adding the namespace did you try using Chart control in your razor view?

Comment: Nope, I did not try to use it. But I have used the WebGrid helper in a production site without issues.
It seemed that you were getting a compile time error. So you get the error at runtime?
Did you add the namespace to the correct web.config as suggested in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did as suggested in your answer before posting the question. I am sure you might have used WebGrid, coz both web grid and charting are also available under the System.Web.Helpers namespace. Charting under System.Web.Helpers namespace has limited functionality and I was looking to use the one available under System.Web.UI.DataVisualization instead... This is where I hit this problem.